# Render Partial View in Layout MVC 4 with Caching and Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm new to MVC.NET and I'm working with MVC4 .
In a project I should return System Information like Post count, User counts and etc. In My _Layout I have defined a Sidebar which will show these data.
here is my sidebar div

```
<div class="sideElement">
     <div class="header">
          مشخصات سیستم
     </div>
     <div class="body">
          @{Html.Action("GatherSystemInfo","Home").ToString();}
     </div>
</div>
```

My GatherSystemInfo Action is Like This : 
Of Course I have used static data For testing

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=900, VaryByParam = "none")]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GatherSystemInfo(SystemInformation model = null)
    {            
        model.QuestionCount = 10930;
        model.ToturialCount = 10353;
        model.UserCount = 120123;
        model.ProjectsNumber = 10231;
        model.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        model.OnlineUsers = 28;
        return PartialView("_SystemInfo", model);
    }
```

And My Partial View Is like this:

```
@model Persiangeeks.Models.SystemInformation

<div class="infoContainer">
    <div class="rightFloated sysInfoTitle">تعداد سوالات ثبت شده : </div>
    <div class="leftFloated sysInfoValue">@Html.Raw(Model.QuestionCount)</div>
    <div class="clear" ></div>
</div>
<div class="infoContainer">
    <div class="rightFloated sysInfoTitle">تعداد آموزشهای موجود : </div>
    <div class="leftFloated sysInfoValue">@Html.Raw(Model.ToturialCount)</div>
    <div class="clear" ></div>
</div>
<div class="infoContainer">
    <div class="rightFloated sysInfoTitle">تعداد پروژه های موجود : </div>
    <div class="leftFloated sysInfoValue">@Html.Raw(Model.ProjectsNumber)</div>
    <div class="clear" ></div>
</div>
<div class="infoContainer">
    <div class="rightFloated sysInfoTitle">تعداد کاربران ثبت شده : </div>
    <div class="leftFloated sysInfoValue">@Html.Raw(Model.UserCount) نفر</div>
    <div class="clear" ></div>
</div>
<div class="infoContainer">
    <div class="rightFloated sysInfoTitle">تعداد کاربران آنلاین : </div>
    <div class="leftFloated sysInfoValue">@Html.Raw(Model.OnlineUsers) نفر</div>
    <div class="clear" ></div>
</div>
```

But When I run my project I have Nothing to show in my sidebar div. here is the Image

[image]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: did u try @{Html.RenderAction("GatherSystemInfo","Home")} instead of   @{Html.Action("GatherSystemInfo","Home").ToString();}

Comment: use `RenderAction()` in place of `Action()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.Action()` – Outputs string

`Html.RenderAction()` – Renders directly to response\

**Solution :** use `RenderAction()` in place of `Action()`

Comment: Thank you Buddy. It Works. And another Question ,Is my Caching Syntax true? Does it Work?

Comment: Yes the syntax is correct ...You can also set `NoStore` value for your chaching to False

Comment: Thank You Friend @Tushar Gupta